# Meaning of profane phrase. "S don't mean s."

Tags: meaning

I'm reading Finders Keepers by Stephen King. Does anyone know what "Shit don't mean shit" means?

Answer (score 1):

"Don't mean shit" = of no consequence.

The first "shit" seems to act like a pronoun. If the original noun isn't directly referenced then I'd guess it is talking about general life events.

Answer (score 0):

Morris says it while he's being raped in prison, so it might mean

"It doesn't matter. It won't affect me."

Something like - Stupid things don't affect me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have mastered the context to get the meaning.  Stephen King's book is the story of the murder of a reclusive writer named Rothstein and the secret burial of and the subsequent search for Rothstein's valuable manuscripts. King prefaces his book with two quotes.  The first from Joseph Campbell:

> It is by going down into the abyss that we recover the treasures of
>   life.

Campbell studied and wrote about mythology and comparative religion.  He maintained that all mythic narrative is part of a single overarching story. His quote means that you discover the important things in your life by confronting the unknown and the fearsome.

The second quote is from Jimmy Gold, who's a fictional character in Rothstein's books:

> Shit don't mean shit.

The first *shit* can mean either 1) whatever meaningless uproar is going on in life or 2) ultimately worthless physical possessions.  The second *shit* means the worth of excrement, in other words nothing.

It's all very wry and self-referential, with the contrast between the abstract goals of (the real) Campbell, who wrote about narratives, and the treasure of King's story as evaluated by (the fictional) Gold, who appears in a narrative within *Finders Keepers*.